# How do I reference matlab variables in a unix command within matlab command line?

Tags: matlab

## Background

I have a variable called `bridgeRoot` defined as such:

`/over/the/river/and/through/the/woods`

This directory has the following subdirectories:

```
/logs
/txt
/bins
```

In matlab command line, when I type `bridgeRoot` I get the value of the variable appropriately:

```
>> bridgeRoot

bridgeRoot = 

/over/the/river/and/through/the/woods
```

However, when I try to `cd` to a subdirectory, I get the following error

```
>> command = 'cd bridgeRoot/logs'

>> system(command)

Error bridgeRoot/logs: No such file or directory

status = 1
```

This works when done as part of a matlab script, but for some reason it fails while in command line.

## Question

How do I properly refernce matlab variables when invoking a unix command in matlab command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `command = ['cd ' bridgeRoot '/logs']` to use the contents of your variable `bridgeRoot` rather than the text 'bridgeRoot'.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `>> command = 'cd bridgeRoot/logs'`, this way it's a string which is never interpreted. The best option to concatenate two parts of a path is to use the `fullfile` command. Further I am not sure if you want to call the matlab function cd or the os command. For the matlab function:

```
cd(fullfile(bridgeRoot,'logs'))
```

for the os command:

```
system(['cd ',fullfile(bridgeRoot,'logs')])
```

The later would only make sense once you add further commands. The `cd` only changes the working directory for other commands within that call of system.